# What is the limit of marketing cloud to add rows in a data extension at a time?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ssjs, automation

I am trying to add around 3 lacs records in data extension in batches of 2500
by calling api inside script activity
below api i am using to add data in DE:

> https://mcdlxf0ptr61tcvgvx1g1521cg91.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/data/v1/async/dataextensions/key:allsubde/rows

But automation stops in between without adding all records it could add around 237000 records in DE.

Is there any other way to add around 5 lacs records in DE using script activity of automation.

Comment: What is the source of this data? Another DE? Normally I would just use a Query Activity for this

Comment: Sounds like the wrong design pattern. Lukas is correct when a DE is the source, otherwise, go flat files and import with Automation Studio.